# Cavalier challenge bonus

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, attack

I started playing a level 10 two weapon fighter samurai and had a question from the first game last night about part of the Challenge ability:

> The cavalier's melee attacks deal extra damage whenever the attacks
>   are made against the target of his challenge. This extra damage is
>   equal to the cavalier's level.

Does this ability apply to every hit? (4 x sucessful hits = 40 bonus damage?) or just the overall damage at the end ( 4 x hits result + 10)? I think it's to every hit (the text specifies attacks plural) but others were unsure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it applies to every successful attack, like it says in the ability. Works just like paladin's smite evil and various other abilities in the game.